# How to read key value in JSON output without using index

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here is a sample JSON output

```
myJSON = {

    { "results": [
        {
          "data1": 123.45,
          "data2": 67.89
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to directly read `data1`:

```
mydata1 = myJSON['data1']
```

I get an error `KeyError: 'data1'`. I can only find a way to do this by using an index:

```
mydata1 = myJSON['results'][0]['data1']
```

Is there a way to directly read the value in `data1` without having to specify an index for `results`? Or is an index required? Just trying to find a more compact / elegant solution here.

Comment: That's not valid JSON, it needs another set of `{}` around it.

Comment: The index is required. You could loop over the array and read the value from each object in the array. Usually when there's an array it's because there could be more than one item.

Comment: There's no built-in shortcut that accesses properties from the first element of the array. You could define a function to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much a simpler way.
I would do that with this technique:

```
myJSON = myJSON['results'][0]
```

Now you can directly access data1 and data2

```
print(myJSON['data1'])
```

And the output will be `123.45`

Comment: They don't want to use index `myJSON['results'][0]`

Comment: I think this is not a bad solution, actually. It saves me from having to indicate the index every time, makes for more readable code in my particular case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your json is :

```
myJSON = {

    "results": [
        {
          "data1": 123.45,
          "data2": 67.89
        }
      ]
}
```

If you want to get `data1` without using index you can use for loop. this will take O(N) time:

```
for x in myJSON["results"]:
  mydata1 = x['data1']

print(mydata1)
#123.45
```

Or List comprehension:

```
mydata1 = [x['data1'] for x in myJSON["results"]]

print(*mydata1)
#123.45
```

Ideally,it should be with O(1) time

```
mydata1 = myJSON['results'][0]['data1']
```

Or

```
mydata1 = myJSON['results'][-1]['data1']
```